# Persistance in JBoss wildfly (in a spring application)

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence, jboss7.x, wildfly

I have a spring 3.2 application which has defined persisence with the following configuration:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <entry key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />
        <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        <entry key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory" />
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
</util:map>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>      
        <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource"  />
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager" >
        <property name="packagesToScan"  value="gr.hcg.nautologhsh.domain" />
        <property name="defaultJtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

My entity classes exist under the gr.hcg.nautologhsh.domain package. I am not using any `persistance.xml` files.

Now, this configuration is working fine in JBoss 8 wildfly. However when I see the Administration console of JBoss, in the tag JPA, I don't see any persistance units.

From some googling I think that the persistence units have to be configured through JBoss and not through Spring in order to be visible there - is that true ? I can't really understand why there could be different PUs in JBoss - how can they be used ? The documentation of JBoss is very spartian in that subject and I couldn't understand many things :(

Can somebody explain to me how can I define JBoss persistence units and show these in the JPA tag of wildfly's administration console ?

**Update**

I created a persistence.xml with the following contents:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="nautologhshPU" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/nautologhsh</jta-data-source>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

changed my `datasource-config.xml` beans like ths:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup  id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/nautologhsh" resource-ref="false" />

<tx:jta-transaction-manager  />

<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/env/jpa/EntityManager" id="entityManager" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManager" />
```

and added the following to `web.xml`

```
<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>jpa/EntityManager</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>nautologhshPU</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

And now get the following error:

```
20:24:41,839 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Nautologhsh.war#nautologhshPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Nautologhsh.war#nautologhshPU": org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:169) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:463) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Beta3.jar:1.0.0.Beta3]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:178) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1837)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:396)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:846)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:151) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]
        ... 8 more

20:24:41,861 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Nautologhsh.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"Nautologhsh.war#nautologhshPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Nautologhsh.war#nautologhshPU\": org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]"}}
```

Does any body know what is this `org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]` ??

Comment: Looks like you're using wildfly 8.0.0.Beta1, but there's been a beta2 for a few weeks. Can you try with this one ?

Comment: Ok I will and update again - thanks !

Comment: Hello - are you sure there is a Beta 2 ? I can't find it here: http://wildfly.org/downloads/ :(

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's not released yet. I have a build from the sources on my machine, hence my mistake.

Comment: No problem -- however I am still seeing the error described in my update :(

Comment: Wildfly 8.0.0.CR1 was released yesterday. Would you mind giving it a try and see if the error still occurs ?

Comment: Great ! A nice present for Christmas :) I'll check it and come back with the results !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this quickstart example: https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/blob/master/greeter-spring which uses a `META-INF/persistence.xml` file an in which Spring configuration uses lookups to retrieve the EntityManager and the Datasource from Wildfly:

```
<!-- Look up the database in JNDI -->
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" id="dataSource"
  expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- Look up the container deployed EntityManager -->
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/env/hello/EntityManager"
  id="entityManager" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManager" />
```

(https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/blob/master/greeter-spring/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-business-context.xml)

Comment: This is a nice example! I see that there is a container deployed EntityManager with a ``jndi-name="java:comp/env/hello/EntityManager"``. However I can't really understand *where* is this EntityManager defined ? I mean how do we know that our entity manager has this jndi name (hello/EntityManager)?

Comment: The EntityManager is provided by Wildfly itself (it already comes with Hibernate). So you just have to use inject it in your Spring beans, but it's not your Spring application's duty to initialize it ;-)

Comment: Yes I understand that - what I didn't get was how did you know that the JNDI name of the EntityManager is actually ``hello/EntityManager`` ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Good point actually: the binding is declared in the web.xml deployment descriptor: `<persistence-context-ref>
        <persistence-context-ref-name>hello/EntityManager</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>helloPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>`

Comment: Can you take a look at my updated question ? Thanks !

Comment: The link to the example on Github is broken.   https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/greeter-spring/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-business-context.xml  <= 404

Comment: Ah, found it:

https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/blob/master/greeter-spring/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-business-context.xml